# Docker-compose yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting the following error when running docker-compose up :

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 12, column 17
```

I have no idea why I get this error, I tried using yaml validators and the file is OK.
Could someone give me a little help on this ? Thanks in advance

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  appA:
    image: myimage

  appB:
    image: mysecondImage
    ports:
        - "80:3000"
    volumes:
        -type: bind
          source: /home/user/folder/src
          target: /data
```

I'm using docker-compose version 1.25.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's a direct copy/paste, you need a space between `-` and `type` so that it's

`- type`

instead of

`-type`

I make that goof all the time, too.

Comment: Oh thank you ! I can't believe I have spent almost 2h on this

Comment: @asdfasdfwe No problem! Glad that was it! Again, I make that mistake ALL THE TIME. YAML is pretty sensitive. Try to find a YAML linter for your code editor ;). And please "accept" the answer if it did, indeed, solve your issue.